# UWP ProgressBar and Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, winrt-xaml, inotifypropertychanged

I have very strange situation with updating `ProgressBar`.
Basically, I have `SemanticZoom` and in `ZoomedIn` mode I have `ListView`. Each `ListView` contains `ProgressBar`. And here's the most interesting.

Working (values set by me):

```
<ProgressBar Minimum="1488240000" Maximum="1488241000" Value="{Binding CurrentTime, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Not working (values are binding):

```
<ProgressBar Minimum="{Binding Start, Mode=OneTime}" Maximum="{Binding Finish, Mode=OneTime}" Value="{Binding CurrentTime, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

The way it's not working like that:
`Start` is binded, OK. `Finish` is binded, OK. `CurrentTime` is binded, `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(CurrentTime)))` trigged, but here:

```
public double CurrentTime
    {
       get
       {
          return currentTime;
          //It's trigged only first time
          //But should be triggered every time PropertyChanged triggered
       }

       set
       {
          currentTime = value;
          PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(CurrentTime)));
          //It's OK, it's trigged every time I update this property
       }
    }
```

So, there's definitely something up to getter. Any ideas?

By the way, when I play with position of properties of `ProgressBar` I have strange results. For example, if I set `Minimum`, then `Maximum` and then `Value` I have `ProgressBar` 100%. If I set `Value`, `Maximum` and `Minimum` - it's OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When binding [Minimum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.rangebase#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_RangeBase_Minimum) and [Maximum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.rangebase#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_RangeBase_Maximum) values in Extensible Application Markup Language (XAML), declare the [Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding) for [Maximum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.rangebase#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_RangeBase_Maximum) first. If the [Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding) for [Maximum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.rangebase#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_RangeBase_Maximum) is declared after [Minimum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.rangebase#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_RangeBase_Minimum), the bound value for [Maximum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.rangebase#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_RangeBase_Maximum) is ignored and the following situations can occur:
>
> - If the bound [Minimum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.rangebase#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_RangeBase_Minimum) value is negative, the [Maximum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.rangebase#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_RangeBase_Maximum) value is set to 0.
> - If the bound [Minimum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.rangebase#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_RangeBase_Minimum) value is greater than the default [Maximum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.rangebase#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_RangeBase_Maximum) (100 for [Slider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.slider) and [ProgressBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.progressbar)), the [Maximum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.rangebase#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_RangeBase_Maximum) value is set equal to the [Minimum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.rangebase#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_RangeBase_Minimum) value.
>
> To avoid this behavior, declare the [Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding) for [Maximum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.rangebase#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_RangeBase_Maximum) first in your Extensible Application Markup Language (XAML).

For more info, please see **Note** under [Maximum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.rangebase#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_RangeBase_Maximum) property.

And while binding [Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.rangebase#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_RangeBase_Value) property, the [Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding) must be `TwoWay`. So you can change your code like the following:

```
<ProgressBar Maximum="{Binding Finish, Mode=OneTime}" Minimum="{Binding Start, Mode=OneTime}" Value="{Binding CurrentTime,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Then it should be able to work.

Comment: Yeah, it's perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think this will fix it

```
    <ProgressBar
        Minimum="{Binding Min, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
        Maximum="{Binding Max, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
        Value="{Binding Progress, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    </ProgressBar>
```